# IN in an IF condition

Tags: apex, if

This may sound silly but I was wondering if we can use an `IN` in a `IF` condition.

I know we can do this in a query but suppose if I need to run multiple `IF` conditions on a particular object, it doesn't make sense to have multiple queries but have a single query and iterate over it.

So instead of

```
if(l.Status == 'Dead' || l.Status == 'Cold' || l.Status == 'Duplicate')
```

can I have something like

```
List.add('Dead','Duplicate','Cold');
if(l.Status IN List)
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: In a language like Python, you can do `if l.Status in ('Dead', 'Duplicate', 'Cold'):`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a [Set](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm) that contains unique values and check if this `Set` contains value to check.

```
Set<String> availableStatuses = new Set<String> {
    'Dead',
    'Duplicate',
    'Cold'
    };

if(availableStatuses.contains(l.Status)) {}
```

Comment: +1 but. There's one pitfall with this approach: `System.debug('a' == 'A');
System.debug(new Set<String>{'a', 'b', 'c'}.contains('A'));`. Comparison of strings used in Sets (and as Map keys) is case sensitive so if you go this route - make sure to for example add your picklist vals lowercase and then also slap `toLowerCase()` on the value you're comparing to.